# Google Storage Limits not applying to users, groups or OUs

Tags: google-workspace, g-suite-administrator

I'm trying to manage a user's storage. Their limit is somehow set to 130GB.

The limit says it is inherited from their OU, but when I check the OU settings, it's not there. This user is the only user in the org with this specific storage limit.

According to the documentation, per user limits are set at the Group or OU level, and there is no way to set the limit on an individual user.

Given this, I can't see how or why this particular user has a special limit, given their OU settings. I've also checked any groups, and the groups have no special storage settings either.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Click the (?) (help) button in the Admin web app (it's visible in all the screenshots), review the docs thoroughly, then tell us your most relevant findings and why they don't meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks, I've added what the docs say